# In phone number validation 9,10,14 digit numbers should be valid,if number start with + then any digit number should be valid

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

In my phone number validation i need to validate only 9,10,14 digit numbers and 11,12,13 numbers are not valid,if phone number start with + then any digit number should be valid.Any  preg_match code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
preg_match('/(?=^\d{9,10}$)|(?=^\d{14}$)|(?=^\+\d*)/', '+123456789012', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```